# VHDL recursive component/entity

Tags: recursion, configuration, vhdl

I hope this is possible. I want to be able to write recursive code like this:

```
entity myEntity
    generic (
      size : natural  -- a power of 2
    )
    port (
       -- whatever
    );
end;

architecture structural of myEntity is
begin
    smallerEntity : entity component.myEntity(structural)
        generic map (
            size => size/2
        );
        port map ( 
            ... 
        );
end;
```

So each architecture instantiates a smaller version of itself. At some value of the generic 'size' I want to have a different implementation however.

Can this be done with configurations? If so, how?

As to why I'd like to be able to do this - so I can build reusable code for computing FFTs/DCTs and similar transforms.

Comment: There's a classic paper by Peter Ashenden called "Recursive and Repetitive Hardware Models in VHDL" which you can search for on Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** use recursion in VHDL. But you need to encapsulate your instantiation in an `if-generate` statement. Something like:

```
recursive_structure : if size/2 > 0 generate 
    smallerEntity : entity <library_name>.myEntity(structural)
        generic map (
            size => size/2
        )
        port map ( 
            ... 
        );
end generate recursive_structure;
```

Comment: even if the generate statement is inside the architecture of myEntity? this is new to me.

Comment: @Stacey : that is the point of VHDL's insistence on "separate compilation" - the entity is compiled first, which means it can be used in any design, before the matching architecture is written.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like:

```
-- convert natural to min vector length
function min_len_uns(arg : natural) return natural is       
begin 
     case arg is

         when 1 | 0 =>
            return 1;
         when others =>
            return 1 + min_len_uns(arg/2);
     end case;
end;
```